# How do you submit a widget for the wordpress directory?

Tags: widgets

Looking for this process but for Wordpress:
https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/gadgets/gadgets_for_blogger#testing-style-fonts-and-colors

Thanks.

Comment: WordPress.org plugin [developer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the widget to a plugin and submit the plugin to the [plugin directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/).